# Using Extension Points: no configurable elements found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rich-client-platform

i created an extension point for one plugin(A). Another plugin(B) is setup as an extension to the ep from the first plugin.

When trying to use the extension point eclipse in A eclipse tells me that, it is not able to find configurable elements for the this extension point. The extension point itself is found.

I'm suspecting plugin B is not started at all. How can i check this?

Here is the code, where the extension point gets called:

```
IExtensionRegistry extensionRegistry = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
        IExtensionPoint[] extensionPoints = extensionRegistry.getExtensionPoints("A.extensionpoints");
        //Prints both defined EP's
        for (IExtensionPoint iExtensionPoint : extensionPoints) {
            System.err.println(iExtensionPoint.getUniqueIdentifier());
            System.err.println(iExtensionPoint.getExtensions().length); 
        }
        IExtensionPoint extensionPoint = extensionRegistry.getExtensionPoint("A.extensionpoints.HavingProblemsWith");
        System.err.println(extensionPoint.getLabel());//Prints the Label
        System.err.println(extensionPoint.getConfigurationElements().length);// => 0
```

Comment: Check if B is part of your launch-config. There is no need to start the bundle to read the extensions. Show us relevant code.

Comment: Oh, i forgot... using eclipse 3.5 platform.

Comment: Yes, the plugin is in the run config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up eclipse with the `-console` option. Then you have tools to view the status of the plugins and to start them, if you want so. It may give you some ideas on *why* the plugin hasn't been started.